# Proving One electron wave in nearest orbit of hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, home-experiment

My physics assignment had this question:

"Show that the orbit nearest to the nucleus in a hydrogen atom accommodates
one electron wave. Given that the energy of the electron in the orbit is 13.6 eV.
Given: E = 13.6 eV Radius of the orbit = 5.3x10^(-11)m"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 = 13.6$ eV, so $v = \sqrt{\frac{2E}{m}} = \frac{2\times (13.6 \rm{eV})\times(1.60\times 10^{-19} J/eV)}{9.11\times10^{-31} \rm{kg}} \approx 2.19 \times 10^6$ m/s. Note that this velocity is far from relativistic, so we don't have to worry about that.

From the electron's velocity we can calculate the momentum $p = mv = \hbar k = \frac
{h}{2 \pi} \frac{2 \pi}{\lambda} = \frac{h}{\lambda}$, where $\lambda$ is the electron's wavelength. From this:

$\lambda = \frac{h}{mv} = \frac{6.63\times10^{-34} \rm m^2 kg/s}{9.11\times 10^{-31} \rm kg \times 2.19\times 10^6 m/s} \approx 3.32 \times 10^{-10}$ m.

The radius of the orbit is given to be $r = 5.3 \times 10^{-11}$ m, so the circumference of the orbit is $2\pi r = 2\pi \times 5.3 \times 10^{-11} \approx 3.33 \times 10^{-11}$.